# Load video in same HTML page

Tags: html, video, load

I want to load videos in the same HTML page. The video is already working and linked to a button, but the video is opening itself in a new page. Do I miss some code?

Code:

```
<div id="van_ons"><li><a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov"><img src="knoppen/van_ons.png" /><img src="knoppen/van-ons.png" /></a></li></div>
```

Player & buttons code:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="buttons">

    <ul>

        <div id="van_ons"><li><a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov" target="_self"><img src="knoppen/van-ons.png" /></a></li></div>

        <div id="krijg_je"><li><a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov"><img src="knoppen/krijgje.png" /></a></li></div>

        <div id="iig"><li><a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov"><img src="knoppen/iniedergeval.png" /></a></li></div>

        <div id="een_witte_kerst"><li><a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov"><img src="knoppen/eenwittekerst.png" /></a></li></div>



    </ul>

</div>





<div id="achtergrond">
        <!-- Begin VideoJS -->
  <div class="video-js-box">
    <!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
    <video class="video-js" width="500" height="400" controls preload poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">

      <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. -->
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png", {"url": "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
        <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
        <img src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" width="400" height="500" alt="Poster Image"
          title="No video playback capabilities." />
      </object>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not as easy as inserting a link. Use a player, e.g. http://jplayer.org

Comment: never tried a player before, but i will try this for now...thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
<a href="onderdelen/movies/santa.mov" target="_self"><img src="knoppen/van_ons.png" /></a>
```

Comment: I think it is a solution, but when I add this code, my button (img) disappears...

Answer (score 0):

You can embed videos using the [object tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp) or the [HTML5 video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp), although you may run into codec or browser incompatibility issues. So I suggest one of the following:

- For an easy solution which works everywhere, upload the video on a
  video hosting platform like Youtube and copy/paste the HTML you get
  there in your web page.
- Use a video player library like flowplayer or jplayer, this is a bit harder to implement but you won't have the Youtube branding and your video is kept private.

Comment: Thank you! First I will try a player, but I have no idea how to link this to my buttons. I shall add my new code with  player above, so you can take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

youll have to use a player like flowplayer to embed the video on your page.
http://flowplayer.org/ 
or you can use HTML5 video- but youll need mp4 (H.264) or OGG video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

Comment: I want to use this HTML5 code, but not want to work with .fla. How can I add a video to a button, so the video loads it self in the same webpage?

Comment: i'm not clear, do you want to click a button that loads a video on that page?

Comment: if that is the case, then i suggest you use jplayer or flowplayer.. because no browser currently supports flv in the <video> tag :/